# Combine count of word pairs: python

Tags: python, mapreduce

I wrote a mapper that prints out word pairs and a count of 1 for each of them.

```
import sys
from itertools import tee


for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip()
    words = line.split()

def pairs(lst):
    return zip(lst,lst[1:]+[lst[0]])

for i in pairs(words):
    print i,1
```

I tried writing a reducer that creates a dictionary, but I am a bit stuck on how to sum them up.

```
import sys

mydict = dict()
for line in sys.stdin:
    (word,cnt) = line.strip().split('\t') #\t
    mydict[word] = mydict.get(word,0)+1

for word,cnt in mydict.items():
    print word,cnt
```

But it says there are not enough arguments in the .split line, thoughts? Thank you.

Comment: each time you are done iterating through `for line in sys.stdin:` , `words` ends up equaling the very last line, and the very last line alone. So what exactly does your `sys.stdin` look like?

Comment: after splitting **line** it becomes a **list**

Comment: why are you using `(word,cnt) ` when you never use `cnt`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is `(word,cnt) = line.strip().split('\t') #\t` 
The `split()` method returns a list, and tries to assign it to `(word, cnt)`, which does not work because the number of items doesn't match (maybe there's sometimes only one word). 
 Maybe you want to use something like

```
for word in line.strip().split('\t'):
    mydict[word] = mydict.get(word, 0) + 1
```

If you have problems with empty list elements, use `list(filter(None, list_name))` to remove them.

**Disclaimer:** I didn't test the code. Also, this only refers to your second example